# How to search or filter List<Class> from JSON array?

Tags: android, json

I have one class, class Patient and inside of that class, there is a List of Medicine. The data/values come from the JSON array it looks like this:

**Classes:**

```
class Patient{
     private string patientName;
     private string patType;
     private int patTxId;
     private List<medicine> medicines;  
}

class medicines{
    private string medId;
    private string itemDesc;
    private int qty;
}
```

**JSON:**

```
[
  {
     "patientName": "John Doe",
     "patType": "I",
     "patTxId": "100021",
     "medicines": [
        {
           "medId": "M000021",
           "itemDesc": "Aspirin",
           "qty" : "2"
        },
        {
           "medId": "M000052",
           "itemDesc": "Paracetamol",
           "qty" : "5"
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "patientName": "Jane Doe",
     "patType": "I",
     "patTxId": "100056",
     "medicines": [
        {
           "medId": "M000021",
           "itemDesc": "Aspirin",
           "qty" : "5"
        }
     ]
  }
]
```

I want to filter the list from one patient having many medicines to one medicine having many patients based on the specific medicine. It looks like this:

```
Aspirin:
2 John Doe
5 Jane Doe

Paracetamol:
5 John Doe
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: mauy be having a map<Medcines,List<Names>)

Comment: _Is there any way to do this?_ - Of course there is. What have you tried already?

Comment: @fluffy yes, I did several ways like looping through lists and predicates

Comment: @Rocky please provide your not working solution(s) by adding them to the question. It would clarify your issue pretty much.